# Google Cloud SQL return "Update failed: An unknown error occurred" when updating database variables

Tags: database, postgresql, gcloud

I tried to turn-on the autovaccum and the Google cloud return the error below and did not update nothing in the databas although the front shows that the variables were set :

How can I found out the log of a generic error caused by updating Google cloud "Database flags"?

Ps: The client do not pay the Google Cloud support and the GCP slack group do not answer my question and none of my messages.

[image: database flag]

[image: unknown error message]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like autovaccum flag modification is [supported](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres) so it is not likely that that is the cause. Rather "An unknown error occurred" can have many causes so I suggest creating a [private issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491274&template=1161130) and specify your Project Id and Cloud SQL instance name so we can take a look at your project directly.